# Поставить условие в Repeater

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Здравствуйте. После обработки данных на сервере данные выводятся в Repeater, который выглядит следующим образом:

```
<asp:Repeater id="repeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>      
        <div class='styled-msg-client'>
            <div class='msg-text'> <p>[<%# Eval("name") %>] : <%# Eval("msg") %></p> </div>
            <div class='msg-time'> <p> <%# Eval("msg_time") %> </p> </div>
        </div>           
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Также в зависимости от данных, которые приходят с сервера нужно в разметку вывести вот этот блок:

```
<asp:Repeater id="repeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>      
        <div class='styled-msg'>
            <div class='msg-text'> <p>[<%# Eval("name") %>] : <%# Eval("msg") %></p> </div>
            <div class='msg-time'> <p> <%# Eval("msg_time") %> </p> </div>
        </div>           
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Отличия между этими блоками только в классе .styled-msg и .styled-msg-client.
В Page_Load прописана такая штука:

```
DataTable dt = showMessages(id_receiver);
repeater.DataSource = dt;
repeater.DataBind();
```

Comment: Отлично, вопрос в чём?

Comment: Вопрос заключается в том как поставить условие? При id_type = 1 нужно вывести первый блок, а при id_type = 0 второй.

Comment: Через `<%= %>` не получается добавить? Ну типа `<%= id_type == 0 ? "styled-msg" : "styled-msg-client" %>`

Comment: Дело в том что значение id_type приходит из БД, а функция Eval("id_type") не работает на таких скобках которые вы советуете.

Comment: Эти скобки всего лишь сокращение для `<% Response.Write(...) %>`, пробуйте

Comment: Кстати, `Eval("id_type")` вам не нужно, так как вам нужно лишь проверить значение переменной `id_type` и вывести константное значение

Comment: я делаю Convert.ToInt32(Eval("id_type")), компилятор ругается

Comment: Ну естественно ругается, вы понимаете что делает `Eval`? `id_type` это что у вас? Поле/свойство некоторого класса?

Comment: нет. поле id_type это колонка в БД. так же как и Eval("msg"), Eval("name").

Comment: Решил) поставил знак # вместо = и все заработало) спасибо вам большое за помощь))

Comment: Отлично, в виде ответа оформите.